# Responsively floating multiple images

Tags: image, css

I've searched high and low, read tutorials and still have no answer for this :-\

What's best-practice for getting 3 images evenly spaced inside a div (one left, one middle, and one right), and keeping the distance between images appearing even as the browser size is reduced? I have tried using width- and margin-%'s with no luck. Is it more appropriate to use an in-line block solution, and if so, how?

Page in question: http://www.1000hours.co.nz/mtc/

html:
I was unable to post the html here despite reading the guide, I'm not sure why? It's in the revised JSfiddle markup: http://jsfiddle.net/87pgzLf1/

css:

```
#divcontainer {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  padding:25px;
  margin: 5px;

#iconcontainer {
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#buttoncontainer {
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 1px;
}

#icon1 {
    float:left;
  margin-left:20%;
}

 #icon2 {
  float:left;
}

#icon3 {
  margin-right:60px;
  float:right;
  padding-left:20%;
}
```

You rule stack exchangers, thanks heaps in advance. Feel free to grab the background images on the page if you like as contribution <3 [disclaimer: this is not a scam but that's up to you to decide. Editors don't hate on people who give please, just because others in the world aren't always trustworthy - I am.]

Comment: What the heck are those `.rar` files in the fiddle? Seems suspicious.

Comment: Removed your fiddle link cause no-one needs instakarma but you. Please don't ever post links to suspicious content, post all the minimal necessary code that reproduces your *issue* inside your question.

Comment: No Josh, I don't. This is for a charity, and I'm an honest person. The option is there for people to choose to trust or not to trust. I have removed the js fiddle from my original edit, however I leave it to the viewer to make up their minds about who they trust. I encourage you to view the link "Matapono", which outlays the principles of the project, before you judge eh? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Roko, how do I include the html? If I post <div id="etc"> </div> nothing shows up. I've revised my js fiddle to use dummy information instead of the live links, so that people who are worried about hostility are kept safe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an update to your jsfiddle:

[**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/87pgzLf1/1)

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for the update, this has been helpful! I now have the images themselves scaling in size, but the distance between them doesn't seem to change? I'd like the PC icon to sit at the right of the div, the Pad icon to sit in the middle, and the Phone icon to sit at the left? I've updated the website anyway so you can see the progress :-) I would have upvoted your response but apparently I need a reputation of 15 ;-)